# How to remove site contents from the navigation bar of the wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I edited the master page and commented out the below:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">
                <%--<div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
                    <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                        runat="server"
                        id="idNavLinkViewAll"
                        PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                        NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
                        Text="<%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%>"
                        accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                        CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" />
                </div>--%>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

but I am still seeing the site content. I couldn't find site content in the navigation under site settings either.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options to remove `Site Content` from the left naviagtion

- Via CSS
- Via Edit links Settings.
- Via Permissions.

---

**Via CSS**, try to use this CSS in Script Editor or in your master Page

```
<style>
#sideNavBox a[href$="/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"]
 {
    display: none;
 }
</style>
```

---

Via Edit Links Settings,

- In the left navigation, Click on Edit Links

[image]

- Remove links

[image]

---

**Via Permissions.**

Based on the permission assigned to the current user, he will be able to see Site Content or not.

Comment: the option mentioned above is not visible on Wiki sites. you can only edit thouse from the site settings navigation. but for sharepoint online you wont be able to see this option in the site navigation, so i went to the masterpage to remove Site content with the code above. but it still not working. i cant add a css script because Site Content needs to go from all the pages of the site.

Comment: Could you first add the above CSS in script editor just for test and check if it was hidden or not? Second, where you add this CSS in the master page?

Comment: I have added the script provided onto the script editor and it removed the site content from the nav bar . But i wanted is to have the "Site Content" removed from all the pages while creating. Hence adding something like this in masterpage for wiki will be the best option for me.

Comment: where have you added this CSS in MasterPage? try to add it in HTML within the head Tag

Comment: i have added that betweent the head and html where the css is suppose to be and hit save in the sharepoint designer (as i dont seems to find a publish button). but it wont seems to work.